# Download an attachement to a specific path using web api

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

My question is specific around, being able to download an attachment to a particular folder on the clients machine. You can assume, the directory exists for the arguments sake.

Are there any methods to download the attachment to a specified path without having to change the browser default download location?

Here is an example.

```
var response = new HttpResponseMessage();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[16 * 1024];
            MemoryStream ms;
            using (ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                int read;
                while ((read = result.Item2.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                {
                    ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
                }
            }
            response.Content = new ByteArrayContent(ms.ToArray());

            response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
            response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = result.Item1;
            response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/pdf");
            return Ok(response);
```

Comment: Only the client can put the file anywhere.

Comment: I understand that, so for my scenario, I require it to be downloaded to a specific directory. There is a watch on the directory, that "watches" for new file arrivals... not sure what alternative method I could use?